# Are cookies the only way to give a client an instruction from a server to execute some js code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express, cookies

Or in other words: *How to send a client a message from a server to execute some js code on a page?*

It is not an Ajax request, it is a plain `GET` browser-server request.

Let's say, I have this code in my app's front-end javascript file:

```
if( condition_1 ) {
    FB.getLoginStatus(...)
}
else if( condition_2 ) {
    PayPal.getLoginStatus(...)
}
else {
   do smth else...
}
```

So I want to send those `condition_1` or `condition_2` instructions along with server's response. It is not Ajax request. It is a plain `GET` request from a browser to a server.

Only cookies are coming to my mind at the moment.

1) A server receives a GET request from a browser.

2) I read cookies. If there is no certain cookie came along with the request, I set `condition_1`, otherwise I set `condition_2` cookie:

```
if(req.cookies["foo"] == "foo") {
    res.cookies("foo", "condition_1")
       .status(200)
       .send()
       .end();
}
else if(req.cookies["foo"] == "bar") {
    res.cookies("foo", "condition_2")
       .status(200)
       .send()
       .end();
}
```

3) A server sends a 200 response back to client.

Now in a browser I check those cookies (for the sake of simplicity I do `document.cookie.foo`):

```
if( document.cookie.foo == 'condition_1' ) {
    FB.getLoginStatus(...)
}
else if( document.cookie.foo == 'condition_2' ) {
    PayPal.getLoginStatus(...)
}
else {
   do smth else...
}
```

And my question is, are cookies the only way in such a case? To instruct a client-side code to execute some condition

Comment: uhm, cookies are completely irrelevant here. they are meant to be sent to the server along with the request, not the other way around. since you are already doing a GET request you can just answer it and evaluate the answer, or you can use websockets if you want to circumvent requests from the client.

Comment: There are many ways to pass some "context" between request response cycles, like hidden HTML input elements.

Comment: In addition to what @Ankur said, the server may also respond with dynamically generated javascript, either as a separate resource (a .js file) or as an embedded <script> in the HTML: `<script>var myVar1 = {{FILLED_BY_SERVER}}, myVar2 = {{FILLED_BY_SERVER}}; callMyStaticFunctionWithDynamicParameters(myVar1, myVar2);</script>`

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are stored in your browser and send back to the server with each request. It is for storing settings client side, not for sending info from the server.

If you are using some server side technology that can set cookies in the response then why not use it to send the script block you want executed back?

Answer (score 0):

You are making things more complex they need to be: Javascript provides `eval`.

The server can simply reply a string with an expression/statement to evaluate in the browser context. It's not developed at the same level of say Lisp... but even in Javascript "data" can be "code" directly (without the need to raise the logical level by writing an interpreter like is instead required in languages like Java or C++).